# How to map from source list to different destination list

Tags: c#, linq

Given the following source classes:

```
public class Product
{
    public ICollection<ProductColor> Colors {get; set;}
}

public class ProductColor
{
    public ColorEnum Color {get; set;}
}
```

And the following destination classes:

```
public class ColorClass
{
    public ColorEnum Color {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Product> Products {get; set;}
}
```

How is it possible to map (copy) from source to destination using LINQ?

Comment: What is "source" what is "destination" ? you provided the classes, but not the actual objects or collection you are using . Under which rule you are creating the class Color ?  some kind of Cross join ?

Comment: The color class has a syntax error.

Comment: Your destination class is not even compiling because the class name is the same as one of it's members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By flattening the collections and regrouping by color, the following should work:

```
Products.SelectMany(product =>
    product.Colors.Select(color => new { product, color })).
         GroupBy(entry => entry.color.Color). // entry.color is a ProductColor
         Select(group => new Color()
         {
           Color = group.Key,
           Products = group.Select(entry => entry.product).ToList()
         })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class HowToMap
    {
        private IEnumerable<Product> products;
        private IEnumerable<Color> colors;

        void Demo()
        {
            colors = products.SelectMany(r => r.Colors.Select(rr => new { r, rr.ColorEnum }))
                .GroupBy(x => x.ColorEnum)
                .Select(g => new Color { ColorEnum = g.Key, Products = g.Select(x => x.r).ToList() });
        }
    }
```